# Seeing the effects of tree shaking in Angular 4

Tags: angular, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs, tree-shaking

Developing with the recently released Angular 4, I've been following along with [Angular's cookbook for working with the AOT compiler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html), applying their configuration settings to my own tsconfig-aot.json and rollup-config.js files, as well as setting up my main-aot.ts file.  When I got to the end of the tutorial and ran soucre-map-explorer for my build.js file, the result was less detailed than I expected it to be:

[image: My app's source map]

Compare that to the tutorial's source map:

[image: Tutorial's source map]

In my app's source map, I was expecting to see more detail under @angular/core (as in the tutorial's source map), but all I see is core.es5.js.  Maybe the image in the tutorial is for a previous version of Angular and what I'm seeing is to be expected?  Does anyone know why that is?  Again, I'm using Angular 4.

Also, you can see at the top of my source map it says 91kB, but the file size of my build.js file is 252KB.  So, what does that 91kB refer to, and why would it be so much lower than build.js's file size?

Thanks!